# Will my cats properly settle down after taking them back to their old home?

Tags: cats, house-moving

I moved south just over 2 weeks ago with my 2 cats.

I now know that the place is not for me. So I am moving back within a week!

Are my cats still familiar with their home and territory back there? Will they properly settle down over there after this short gap? I can understand that they are not happy here.

Comment: What's your question? Are they settled in after 2 weeks? Or, will they be able to settle in when you move back? Are they unhappy? Or are you projecting your unhappiness onto them?

Answer (score 4):

If you are moving back to the old house with your cats they will remember it. There is absolutely no doubt about it.

Cats have an excellent memory of places where they have been before. There are lots of examples where a cat has been lost for years and when they return, they know where every tree and bush is like it never was gone at all.

Answer (score 2):

**They will remember it** and there's probably still some traces of 'smells' in your old place that they recall which will help them to feel back at home. They'll probably feel just like cats who have been on a "holiday"/"vacation" to a cattery (for boarding cats while you go on holiday).

It may be (but unlikely) that a new neighborhood cat has established their territory in 'your' back yard. They will resolve that between themselves quickly. Especially as you have a 'team' of 2 cats (my experience is that cats who are friends will back each other up in these conflict situations).